# Shell script working only after adding an echo statement just before body of the 'if' block

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to run the below script but it is not executing the if block but when I add another statement `echo "Test"` just below the `if` statement then my `if` block gets executed. Can anyone suggest what is causing this? I am not able to figure out how adding an `echo` statement is making the `if` block execute.

P.S. Please assume that the source and target directories exist and the file also exists in the source directory with the same name as mentioned in the script.

Script not Working:

```sh
if [ -f $/apps/agile/product/xxxxxx.xlsx ]

then

    mv /apps/agile/product/xxxxxx.xlsx /apps/agile/product/Archived
    echo "Moved the last generated Report to Archived Directory"

fi;
```

Working Script:

```sh
if [ -f $/apps/agile/product/xxxxxx.xlsx ]

echo "Test"

then

    mv /apps/agile/product/xxxxxx.xlsx /apps/agile/product/Archived
    echo "Moved the last generated Report to Archived Directory"

fi;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the dollar sign?

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `if` is a sequence of commands. The exit status of the last one of these commands is what `if` examines and acts on.

You are effectively changing

```
if false; then
```

to

```
if false; true; then
```

which succeeds.

The real cause of the error is probably the aberrant `$/` at the beginning of the path. We can't guess what the correct path is, but this is almost certainly incorrect, unless you really have a directory named `$` in the current directory (which would be hugely impractical).

Comment: Thanks...! I removed $ from the directory path and it worked without the echo "Test" statement.